# Beam - Handling failures during huge data load for bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I have recently started with Apache beam. I am sure I am missing something here. I have a requirement to load from a very huge database to bigquery. These tables are huge. I have written sample beam jobs to load minimal rows from simple tables.

1. How would I able to load n number of rows from tables using JDBCIO? Is there anyway that i can load these data in batches as we do in conventional data migration jobs.?
2. Can I do batch read from a database and write in batches to bigquery?
3. Also i have seen that, the suggested approach to load the data to bigquery is by adding the files to the data store buckets. But, in automated environment, the requirement is to write it as a dataflow job to load from db and write it to bigquery. What should my design approach to solve this issue using apache beam?

Please help.!

Answer (score 1):

It looks[1] like BigQueryIO will write batches of data if it comes from a bounded PCollection (otherwise it uses streaming inserts). It also appears to bound the size of each file and batch, so I don't think you'll need to do any manual batching.

I'd just read from your database via JDBCIO, transform it if needed, and write it to BigQueryIO.

[1] https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java